# Ubuntu 12.10: No WiFi After Update on Dell XPS L502x w/ Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

It had been months since I had booted my Ubuntu partition so I fired it up yesterday evening and immediately ran a "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade". The update apparently finished without issue and asked me to reboot. As I had some other business to do I shut the laptop down and booted on Windows instead for the rest of the night. Today I rebooted on Ubuntu to find out that the WiFi adapter won't connect to my box anymore.

I can see the list of the available wifi networks and the adapter keeps trying to connect to my box but each time I see the spinner icon spin for a while and it ends with a "Wireless network Disconnected" toast notification.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Thomas

Here are the results from a few commands, please ask if you need me to run anything else:

$ lspci -vvnn | grep Network

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [8086:008a] (rev 34)
```

$ lspci -vvnn (relevant excerpt)

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

excerpt from syslog showing about 2 full consecutive attempts at connecting

```
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Auto-activating connection 'Livebox-7435'.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Livebox-7435'
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Livebox-7435' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Livebox-7435' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'ssid' value 'Livebox-7435'
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'psk' value ''
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (SSID='Livebox-7435' freq=2437 MHz)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.825723] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (try 1)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Trying to associate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (SSID='Livebox-7435' freq=2437 MHz)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.828775] wlan0: authenticated
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.836444] wlan0: associate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (try 1)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.840676] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.840686] wlan0: associated
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Associated with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.845878] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: FR
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854158] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854169] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854175] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854181] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854186] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854191] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854196] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854202] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854206] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854212] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854217] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854223] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854227] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854233] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854237] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854243] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854247] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854253] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854258] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854263] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854268] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854273] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854278] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854284] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854288] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854294] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854301] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: FR
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854305] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854311] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854316] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854320] cfg80211:     (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo kernel: [ 1787.854325] cfg80211:     (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Livebox-7435'.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  dhclient started with pid 5199
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: 
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/ac:72:89:45:2e:fa
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/ac:72:89:45:2e:fa
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul 29 18:12:37 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.12 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 29 18:12:47  dhclient: last message repeated 2 times
Jul 29 18:12:47 qwindoo kernel: [ 1798.016842] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
Jul 29 18:12:57 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul 29 18:13:00 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul 29 18:13:05 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul 29 18:13:14 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5199
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (Livebox-7435)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) failed.
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.474562] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 by local choice (reason=3)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.678195] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.678211] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.678222] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688505] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688518] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688524] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688533] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688542] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688550] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688558] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:23 qwindoo kernel: [ 1833.688565] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Auto-activating connection 'Livebox-7435'.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Livebox-7435'
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Livebox-7435' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Livebox-7435' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'ssid' value 'Livebox-7435'
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: added 'psk' value ''
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Trying to authenticate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (SSID='Livebox-7435' freq=2437 MHz)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.800674] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (try 1)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Trying to associate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (SSID='Livebox-7435' freq=2437 MHz)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.803209] wlan0: authenticated
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.803435] wlan0: associate with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (try 1)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.807446] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.807449] wlan0: associated
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: Associated with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.810872] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: FR
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814041] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814045] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814047] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814050] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814051] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814053] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814055] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814057] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814059] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814061] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814063] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814065] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814066] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814068] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814070] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814072] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814074] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814076] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814078] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814080] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814081] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814083] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814085] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814087] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814089] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814091] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814094] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: FR
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814095] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814097] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814099] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814101] cfg80211:     (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo kernel: [ 1836.814103] cfg80211:     (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Livebox-7435'.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  dhclient started with pid 5212
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: 
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/ac:72:89:45:2e:fa
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/ac:72:89:45:2e:fa
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul 29 18:13:26 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.12 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 29 18:13:36  dhclient: last message repeated 2 times
Jul 29 18:13:36 qwindoo kernel: [ 1846.899122] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
Jul 29 18:13:57 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul 29 18:14:00 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul 29 18:14:03 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul 29 18:14:07 qwindoo dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5212
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (Livebox-7435)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) failed.
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.422940] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:33:8e:8e:33:66 by local choice (reason=3)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo wpa_supplicant[1261]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.552491] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.552506] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.552519] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo NetworkManager[923]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.561987] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.561997] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562001] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562008] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562014] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562019] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562024] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:14:12 qwindoo kernel: [ 1882.562029] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```